# Why can't tar extract .zip files?

Tags: tar, zip

I tried a majority of the formats (gzip, etc.) to extract a zip file with `tar`, and when I became frustrated enough to Google for it, I found no way to extract a zip file with `tar` and only recommendations to use `zip` or `unzip`. As a matter of fact, my Linux system doesn't even have a `zip` utility, but only `unzip` (leaving me to wonder why this is the main recommended option). Of course `unzip` worked, solving my problem, but why can't `tar` extract zip files? Perhaps I should instead be asking, what is the difference between zip and the compression methods supported by `tar`?

Comment: Just a note, `bsdtar` can extract `.zip` archives :P

Comment: You mean like in, "why can't I use a can-opener to chop carrots?"  The thing is tar has it's own file-format, and then compresses that with whichever method you choose. zip is a whole different beast. Simple as that.  It's "the unix way", have one small tool that does one job well, rather than having an egg-laying, wool-bearing milk-sow that will cater to all your needs.

Comment: I slightly edited my question to make this clearer, but I think my question clearly implied that I thought zip was a compression format and not a replacement tool for tar+compression. The answer that I chose corrected what I was assuming and showed that the answer wasn't opinion-based.

Comment: You don't have `zip` by default because its licensing is not compatible with GPL

Comment: I want to note that `bsdtar` will extract zip files, however it almost certainly works by buffering the entire zip file into memory before doing any operations with it. This makes it possible to pretend small zip files are streamable (such as from a trusted http server) but its only skin-deep. zip's aren't and can't be streamable so bsdtar won't solve the problem of mixing big data with zip, nor will it really assist with any problems of working with zip other than maybe licensing as bsdtar (libarchive-tools) is released under the BSD-3-clause-UCB license instead of the infozip license.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The UNIX philosophy is to have small tools. One tool is doing exactly one thing, but this especially well.

The `tar` tool is just combining several files into a single file without any compression.

The `gzip` tool is just compressing a single file.

If you want to have both, you just combine both tools resulting in a `.tar.gz` file.

---

The `zip` tool is a completely different thing. It takes a bunch of files and combines them into a single compressed file. With totally different algorithms.

---

If you want one tool to rule them all use `atool`. It will support a [whole bunch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/als.1.html#contenttoc4) of different formats simply by detecting the format and calling the correct tool.

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining the purpose of both instead of just explaining what tar does. I soon figured out the answer after looking at [a wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats "List of archive formats") that listed formats for "Archiving," "Compression," and both in three different tables. I figured I'd wait for an answer that explained this clearly.

Comment: To be a bit picky, the `gzip` compression algorithm is the same one used by `zip`. The difference is that `gzip` is meant to compress any byte stream, including a `.tar` file, while `zip`, derived and inspired by PKZIP, compresses and archives in one step (and in that order).

Comment: This is incorrect. I have used `tar` with `-z` flag to *also* compress/decompress.

Answer (score 22):

Long story short: tar GNU tool doesn't pipe through zip/unzip since nobody cares.

Long story, original size:

`tar` wasn't initially meant for uncompressing and compressing files, but to archiving several files in a single big file. Since people not only wanted to archive their files, but also, compress them, so they just pipe the `tar` output through any compressor that accepts data stream input and drops the results to a file. Profit!

Now, to make such task a painless as possible, `tar` decided to pipe internally the files generated to compression tools, like gzip, lzma, etc., which were activated by special flags for each format when running `tar`. That's why when you try to extract a corrupted file through `tar` you are shown the underlying tool error, instead of `tar`'s:

```
$ tar zxf damaged.tar.gz
gzip: damaged.tar.gz: unexpected end of file
```

So, it isn't that `tar` doesn't uncompress zip files, just that `tar` doesn't have the ability to pipe it through the correct tool, since nobody actually bothered to implement it, and zip already accomplish the file archive function of the tar file format there's less reason for tar to support it.

Now, there are all-in-one tools that compress/uncompress everything you throw at them, again, you need to have the correct tools to actually support it. If you don't have them, the tool will fail.

Comment: Well, beyond just no one implementing the right tool to pipe through, there isn't one: tar files *only* combine multiple files into one. Compression is separate. So the filters tar pipes through just compress/decompress a single tar file. Zip works differently; it uses one integrated tool to compress and combine (a similar Unix program is `afio`).

Comment: I'd suggest mentioning a few of the all-in one compression tools that exist. E.g., there is the GNOME `file-roller`...

Comment: @derobert file-roller only supports zip if you have unzip/zip/p7zip installed. Otherwise is just as useless like tar.

Comment: tar only supports its various compressed versions if you have the relevant tool installed as well... The multi-format archive managers are useful because they give you a consistent interface to handle different archive formats.

Comment: @derobert exactly.

Answer (score 4):

A `tar` file is a file format in itself designed for tape archives.  This format can then be compressed using (for example) `gzip` or `bzip2` compression formats.  When you extract a compressed tar file, you effectively uncompress it, then extract the original files from the uncompressed `tar` file.

When you extract a `zip` file there is no `tar` file within it, just all your original files.  Therefore there is no reason for `tar` to be involved in the process at all.

You can also compress files using `gzip` or `bzip2` by themselves just like you can create `zip` files (with no `tar` involved).  When you uncompress these files, you use `gunzip` or `bunzip2` and not `tar`.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer "Some things just are and we should accept them" does not sit well with me either, I just did some digging (always good to learn something new isn't it?).

So it looks like the issue is one of where the tools went and what their aim was.

Instead of paraphrasing what I found and making the waters needlessly murky (obfuscation pisses me off), take a look at this article: 
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-zip-and-gzip/

I suppose that tar could have built in zip support, but the methodologies are apparently fundamentally different. Or perhaps they thought why would someone use this archiving tool to manage files from another archiving and compression tool (or perhaps there was some argument between the two original coders and there was a restraining order filed that disallowed the zips from crossing the application boundary... yes I am kidding).